# Optimizing query as its slow man

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select distinct m1.jobreference,m1.assid,m2.assid 
From dbo.mess m1
inner join dbo.mess m2 
    on m1.JobReference=m2.jobreference and m1.assid!=m2.assid
where 
m1.jobreference not in ( 
select Jobreference from dbo.mess where routingkey='j.asschanged')
```

4958 row(s) affected)

Table 'Mess'. Scan count 20, logical reads 359816, physical reads 525, read-ahead reads 4626, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.**strong text**

Comment: How can I speed it up is the question ? It takes 3 mins

Comment: What are the table definitions and the actual execution plan as XML.

Comment: Do you have indexes in tables?

Comment: Do you have indexes?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mess](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [JobReference] [int] NOT NULL,
 [JobStatusId] [int] NULL,
 [AssId] [int] NULL,
 [OriginalAssId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Message] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: Non Clustered index on Job Reference and primary index on ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sub-Query` is not needed. Try this way

```
SELECT m1.jobreference,
       m1.assid,
       m2.assid
FROM   dbo.mess m1
       INNER JOIN PRD_Phoenix.dbo.mess m2
               ON m1.JobReference = m2.jobreference
                  AND m1.assid != m2.assid
Group By  m1.jobreference,m1.assid,m2.assid
Having count(case when m1.routingkey = 'j.asschanged' then 1 end) = 0
```

use `Distinct` if you really need to remove duplicates. If your query will not result duplicates or you don't worry about duplicates then remove `DISTINCT` key word from your query

Comment: Strange. It is taking longer with this change. I wonder if there is an issue with stats on this table. Hmmmm...

Comment: @JamesKhan - Just check the updated query. Post the execution plan as xml

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing the query as:

```
select distinct jobreference, assid, assid2
from (select m1.jobreference, m1.assid, m2.assid as assid2,
             sum(case when m2.routingkey = 'j.asschanged' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by m2.jobreference) as cnt
      from dbo.mess m1 inner join
           PRD_Phoenix.dbo.mess m2 
           on m1.JobReference = m2.jobreference and m1.assid <> m2.assid
     ) mm
where cnt = 0;
```

Then you want to think about indexes for the obvious ones are `m2(jobreference, assid)` and `m1(jobference, assid)`.

I am concerned about the `select distinct` and the possibility of high-cardinality joins.  Without more information on the data structures, it is hard to make further suggestions.